# How do I take the Cartesian join of two lists in c#?

Tags: c#, linq

How do I take the Cartesian join of two lists with integers in them?

Can this be done with linq?

Comment: Do you mean an outer product? Cross product is really a vector maths thing.

Comment: @David - Or matrix multiplication :)

Comment: I think he wants a cross join

Comment: Øyvind Are you thinking of tensor product? Cross product is a rather odd operation that can only be performed on vectors of length 3.

Comment: If your vectors are defined as lists with 3 elements, you're probably better off using a cleaner method to represent them. Consider rolling your own Vector class and implementing the math yourself to do things like cross products and normals, and when you get the ideas down switch to a more standard vector class, like the ones you'll find in the XNA framework (for example, im sure there are others).

Answer (score 106):

Assuming you mean a "cross join" or "Cartesian join":

```
var query = from x in firstList
            from y in secondList
            select new { x, y }
```

Or:

```
var query = firstList.SelectMany(x => secondList, (x, y) => new { x, y });
```

If you want something else (as you can see from comments, the term "cross product" has caused some confusion), please edit your question appropriately. An example would be very handy :)

Comment: This one must have been like whiffle ball :)

Comment: The proper term for this is a "Cartesian Product".  Hopefully this is what he wanted, I was scratching my head between this and a true cross product of two vectors.

Comment: That's not the vector product, that's the vector sum. The vector product is only defined on three-dimensional vectors, so it doesn't make a lot of sense to define the vector product on an arbitrary sequence.

Comment: @Eric: Yup, good point... I was trying to guess at what was meant, but it's a sufficiently unlikely guess that it's probably worth removing :)

Comment: Cartesian product is a set operation. So it would make sense to use firstList.Distinct() and seoncList.Distinct() instead of firstList and secondList.

Answer (score 20):

For curiosity, another way to accomplish this (which produces the same result as Jon Skeet's answer) is:

```
firstList.Join(secondList, x => true, y => true, (m, n) => new { m, n });
```

Comment: This is better when you want to cross three lists and the inner one could be empty

Comment: Note that the key selectors don't have to return `true`, they just need to return the same value which will compare equal. You could just as easily return `42` and `42` and it should work.

Comment: Using `Join` should be preferred in this case, where `secondList` is available as a variable and can be provided directly. If you use `SelectMany` (or from ... from ..., which is equivalent) then `secondList` is actually provided in a lambda and will be enumerated multiple times (actually, exactly `firstList.Count()` times). This can be significant performance-wise if any of the lists is large or if enumerating it is expensive, not to mention that multiple enumeration is a bad smell and can produce unexpected results in certain cases.

Answer (score 4):

If you're not fond of the query syntax (like myself), [MoreLINQ](https://morelinq.github.io/) provides [a method](https://morelinq.github.io/3.0/ref/api/html/Overload_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_Cartesian.htm) for it that's cleaner, in my opinion:

```
using MoreLinq;

// ....

firstList.Cartesian(secondList, (x, y) => new { x, y });
```