# How to create a combo list from 2 seperate text files?

Tags: c#, list, foreach, combinations

Hello Dear stackoverflow community, I was making a list editor app and when I don't know how to take [1,2,3,4] and [a,b,c,d,e] and make [1:a, 1:b …, 2:a, 2:b,...] I know it's a simple problem but can't quite find the answer.

I tried linq and foreach but couldn't do what I want.

```
foreach (string text in combo1)
            {
                string final = text + ":" + text;                
            }
```

While I try for each I see cannot convert type char to string. and I want to be able to combine each item from two lists with eachother.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach(var text1 in combo1)
    foreach(var text2 in combo2)
    {
        const combined = text1 + ":" + text2;
        // do something with combined
    }
```

You can find a LINQ solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5004963/871910), but I think the LINQ code is not as clear as two loops.

Comment: well that created what I want, but it replaces itself for eg: if I have abc,def,ghi in combo1 and 123,456,789 in combo 2 it creates a combo on last characters like so i:9. is there a way to add to a string so it ges saved instead of being replaced?

Comment: You can add `combined` to a list every iteration, so you end up with a list of all the strings.